# How to map a series of conditions as keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, lambda

I know you can use a dictionary as an alternative to a switch statement such as the following:

```
def printMessage(mystring):
    # Switch statement without a dictionary
    if mystring == "helloworld":
        print "say hello"
    elif mystring == "byeworld":
        print "say bye"
    elif mystring == "goodafternoonworld":
        print "good afternoon"


def printMessage(mystring):
    # Dictionary equivalent of a switch statement
    myDictionary = {"helloworld": "say hello",
                    "byeworld": "say bye",
                    "goodafternoonworld": "good afternoon"}
    print myDictionary[mystring]
```

However if conditions are used, other than equality (==) which return true of false these cant be mapped as easily i.e.:

```
if i > 0.5:
    print "greater than 0.5"
elif i == 5:
    print "it is equal to 5"
elif i > 5 and i < 6:
    print "somewhere between 5 and 6"
```

The above cannot be directly converted to a dictionary key-value pair as is:

```
# this does not work
mydictionary  = { i > 0.5: "greater than 0.5" }
```

A lambda can be used since it is hash-able but the only way to get the resulting string out of the map is by passing the same lambda object into the dictionary and not when the evaluation of the lambda is true:

```
x = lambda i: i > 0.5
mydictionary[x] = "greater than 0.5"
# you can get the string by doing this:
mydictionary[x]
# which doesnt result in the evaluation of x

# however a lambda is a hashable item in a dictionary
mydictionary = {lambda i: i > 0.5: "greater than 0.5"}
```

Does anyone know of a technique or method to create a mapping between a lambda evaluation and a return value?
(this maybe similar to pattern matching in functional language)

Comment: _"but obviously its only possible when the lambda itself is passed by and not when the evaluation of the lambda is true"_ Sorry, can you rephrase that? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Kevin Okay I have just edited the answer to clarify this point

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your conditions are sequential in nature; you want to test one after the other, not map a small number of keys to a value here. Changing the order of the conditions could alter the outcome; a value of `5` results in `"greater than 0.5"` in your sample, not `"it is equal to 5"`.

Use a list of tuples:

```
myconditions  = [
    (lambda i: i > 0.5, "greater than 0.5"),
    (lambda i: i == 5, "it is equal to 5"),
    (lambda i: i > 5 and i < 6, "somewhere between 5 and 6"),
]
```

after which you can access each one in turn until one matches:

```
for test, message in myconditions:
    if test(i):
        return message
```

Re-ordering the tests will change the outcome.

A dictionary works for your first example because there is a simple *equality test* against multiple static values that is optimised by a dictionary, but there are no such simple equalities available here.

Comment: The parenthesis are not required, but that was what I was about to post.

Comment: @FunkySayu: they are required to group the lambda and message into tuples. Not doing that then requires awkward looping structures.

Comment: Ho okay my bad, i though you were using dictionary instead of list of tuple. By the way, you may add a return statement at the end in case nothing match ?

Comment: Yes, you can add an additional default return if no condition matched. Or you could raise an exception, depending on the use cases.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay, this makes sense -- by sequential nature what you mean is that the conditions themselves are not mutually exclusive and more than one condition can match which gives a many to one relationship and therefore the use of a map is invalidated.

Comment: @Har: yes, order matters here; for `i = 5` your first test already matches so the next won't ever match.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a dictionary to map arbitrary conditionals since more than one of them could be true at the same time. Instead you need to evaluate each one sequentially and execute the associated code the first time a true one is encountered. Here's an outline of one way to formally implement something like that which even allows the equivalent of a `default:` case.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Case = namedtuple('Case', ['condition', 'code'])

cases = (Case('i > 0.5',
            """print 'greater than 0.5'"""),

         Case('i == 5',
            """print 'it is equal to 5'"""),

         Case('i > 5 and i < 6',
            """print 'somewhere between 5 and 6'"""))

def switch(cases, **namespace):
    for case in cases:
        if eval(case.condition, namespace):
            exec(case.code, namespace)
            break
    else:
        print 'default case'

switch(cases, i=5)
```

Output:

```
greater than 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related, but I often use a paradigm similar to the example below for replacing cascading ifs with a dictionaruy lookup.

```
def multipleifs(a=None,b=None,c=None,d=None,e=None):
    """ Func1 with cascaded if
    >>> multipleifs(10,20,30,40,50)
    160
    """

    x=10
    if a:
        x += 10
    if b:
        x += 20
    if c:
        x += 30
    if d:
        x += 40
    if e:
        x += 50

    return x

def dictif(a=None,b=None,c=None,d=None,e=None):
    """ Func2 with dictionary replacing multiple ifs
    >>> dictif(10,20,30,40,50)
    160
    """

    x, mydict = 10, dict(enumerate([10,20,30,40,50]))

    for count, item in enumerate([a,b,c,d,e]):
        if item: x += mydict.get(count,0)

    return x
```